# Marquee in seperate thread in c++ builder 10

Tags: multithreading, c++builder

I have just found that making marquee in the same thread it's text get stopped a little in a time when my application loads data..

I am asking if anybody has done marquee functionality in their application in a seperate thread using TTimer.

Answer (score 3):

Even in you do the marquee in a thread, you still have to synchronize it with the main thread for display, so you will still have the same problem if you continue doing lengthy data loads in the main thread.  So do the data loading in a separate thread instead, and leave the marquee (and all other UI elements and logic) in the main thread, where it belongs.  You should not be doing blocking operations in the main thread to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
HANDLE hThread;
DWORD ThreadId;
int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;

unsigned long __stdcall ThreadFunc(void *Arg)
{
   int a=0;
   while(a != 100000000000000000)
   {
      a++;
      Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(a);
   }

   return 0;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   // hThread=CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadFunc,0,0,&ThreadId);
   hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0,  ThreadFunc, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, &ThreadId);
   if ( hThread == NULL)
   {
      ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);
   }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   TerminateThread(hThread,ThreadId);
}
```

Comment: This is not safe!  You should not call a VCL method in a thread.